# Numerically integrating a highly oscillatory Bessel function with good precision

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

I am trying to evaluate the following integral

```
Integrate[Csch[w]^2 (w BesselJ[1, w Sqrt[y]/π]^2), {w, 0, Infinity}]
```

in an asymptotic large `y` expansion to many orders in `y`. I am having difficulty doing this analytically beyond the lowest couple orders, so I have decided to do it numerically for large `y`, say

```
y = 26000
```

because this is such an oscillatory integral, i have to ask for huge precision to even get low precision results. for instance, I find

```
Precision[
  NIntegrate[(Sinh[w ]^2)^-1 (w BesselJ[1, w Sqrt[26000]/π]^2), {w, 0, Infinity},
    WorkingPrecision -> 45, PrecisionGoal -> 40, AccuracyGoal -> 40]]
```

gives only 10 digits of precision, whereas I wanted 40. Is there some numerical trick to get better results from such an oscillatory integral?

Comment: Have you tried `Method -> "LevinRule"`?

Comment: this works great! thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why the OP says `Method -> "LevinRule"` "works great."  I get an error message that estimates the error in the result to be around the 31st digit, which is greater than the requested precision goal of 40.  The Levin Rule works better, even much better, than the default `"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"` strategy in this case, but not great.  It's possible, judging from the code in the question, that the OP wants only that the [`Precision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Precision.html) of the arbitrary-precision number returned to by `NIntegrate[]` to be the `WorkingPrecision` or at least the `PrecisionGoal`.  If so, there's some misunderstanding: The `Precision` of the result of a numerical solver is independent of the truncation error of the computed result as an approximation of the true solution, except as `Precision` serves as an estimate of the accumulated rounding error and so is lower bound on the truncation error.

If it is the `Precision[]` of the number, then the `"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"` strategy is not a good choice, because `WorkingPrecision` works differently than in other `NIntegrate` methods.  Ultimately the answer is computed by `NSum`.  It computes the terms at `WorkingPrecision`, but in the transformation that produces the sum, [`Precision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Precision.html) is lost, perhaps.  I manually used `NSum` to compute integral, and it took about 350 100-digit terms to get a 40-digit result.  Internally, the `"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"` strategy calls `NSum` with `Method -> {"AlternatingSigns", Method -> "WynnEpsilon"}`.  Obviously, the `"AlternatingSigns"` can't be helping, and maybe it's ignored.

On the other hand, if a more accurate result is desire, the Levin rule in this case can be improved by increasing the number of collocation points:

```
NIntegrate[(Sinh[w]^2)^-1 (w BesselJ[1, w Sqrt[26000]/π]^2),
 {w, 0, Infinity}, PrecisionGoal -> 40, AccuracyGoal -> 40, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 80, Method -> {"LevinRule", "Points" -> 15}]
(*
 0.49379847832739488487909095426686913860800328727627356580918388866276896289397474
*)
```

Comment: (Will upvote later.) I was hoping the OP would go on and look Levin up so he can figure how to tune it better for his problem. It's weird that `"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"` is performing badly; I guess the decay is not sufficiently rapid that catastrophic cancellation sets in already?

Comment: @J.M.iscomputer-less That seems to be the reason.

Comment: I see that in this simple one dimensional case, Levin rule was helpful, but in multidimensional cases I am getting problems. I would like to ask this more complicated question as a follow up question, is there a way of including it in this thread? its over the character limit for a comment

Comment: I havre asked my follow up question here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/183878/numerically-integrating-a-highly-oscillatory-multi-dimensional-bessel-function-w

Answer (score 0):

This integral can be made easier by noting that the singularity at the origin can be integrated analytically

```
Assuming[y > 0, Integrate[w^-2 (w BesselJ[1, w Sqrt[y]/π]^2), {w, 0, Infinity}]]
(* 1/2 *)
```

The residual appears to dealt with relatively easily

```
With[{y = 26000}, 
 NIntegrate[(Csch[w]^2 - w^-2) (w BesselJ[1, w Sqrt[y]/π]^2), {w, 
   0, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 45, PrecisionGoal -> 40, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 40]]
(* -0.00530935354505175 *)
```

The original integral then becomes

```
%% + %
(* 0.49469064645494825 *)
```

Comment: I don't think `-0.005..` is correct -- well, let's say it's inconsistent with `Method -> "LevinRule"`.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, see edited answer

Comment: What I meant to suggest was that the default `Method` in your answer produces the wrong result.  It should be `-0.0062...`, I think.  Try your integral with the Levin rule.  The question then becomes which method gives the right answer.  Well, it's clear to me that `"ExtrapolatingOscillatory"` is having trouble with this integral.   And when I carry it out manually far enough to get a sufficiently accurate result, it agrees with the Levin rule.